# Confidence Interval Question. Final exam review

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, inference

```
We would like to determine whether the true mean systolic blood pressure  of healthy
adults differs from 120. We obtain a sample of healthy adults and conduct an appropriate
hypothesis test, which results in a P-value of 0.021. Which of the following statements
is true?

I. A 96% confidence interval for mu  would contain the value 120.
II. A 98% confidence interval for mu  would contain the value 120.
III A 99% confidence interval for mu  would not contain the value 120.
```

I am doing review for finals and got stuck solving this question. Idk where to start from. I don't want anyone to solve this for me. i just need a hint.

Comment: Start by learning and understanding what a P-value is, and what a confidence interval is. Then apply that knowledge to answer the question.  Presumably, having that knowledge will help you with many potential exam questions. Read a textbook or look at threads on this site.

Comment: As i said i am doing review for finals so that means i know what p value and confidence interval is. I have solved almost all of them questions but this one. @MarkL.Stone

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework or exam prep & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Your question is much too vague to be very suitable. If you know something about p-values and CIs you should be able to say *something*. It suggests you have not performed the basic research required before posting. At the very least, review your text and/or notes and read more widely through some basic internet resources to frame a more specific question than "Idk where to start" before posting. As it stands this would probably be put on hold for any of several different  reasons.

Comment: I didn't make this question. This is from one of MIT's past stats finals. There are times when you just don't know how to solve the question. It doesn't mean that i didn't know anything about the subject hence the" idk where to start". Thanks @Glen_b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The confidence interval width and the p-value are related. For instance, if the p-value is bigger than 0.05, the 95% confidence interval (which is 1-0.05, not a coincidence) will include the null hypothesis value (120). If the p-value is smaller than 0.05, the 95% CI will exclude 120.

Now here is an example, statement I: If we use a 96% confidence interval, any p-value smaller than 0.04 (1-.96) will lead to rejection of null in favor of concluding the mean is different from 120. Now, you actual p-value is 0.021, which is smaller than 0.04. Aka, the null hypothesis should be rejected. We also know if the null is to be rejected, the value to be compared against (120) should be outside of the confidence interval. So, statement I is wrong.